# innerHTML not changing the innerHMTL

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I've tested this code in an old IE and it works, but on everything else that is modern it seems not to work.

The thing is it works only if the textarea hasn't been modified in any way, then after that it doesn't work. Any changes to the page and suddenly it ceases to function.

```
<html>
<script>
function clearArea() {
    document.getElementById("tarea").innerHTML = "This is what\'s up.";
}
</script>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="clearArea()">Click me to clear area</button>
<textarea id="tarea"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried instead updating the textarea's value property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a textarea does not have [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML), it has [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

```js
function clearArea() {
    document.getElementById("tarea").value = "This is what\'s up.";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="clearArea()">Click me to clear area</button>
<textarea id="tarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the value attribute, you can use it instead of innerHTML.

Here a demonstration: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kowaxuhowo/1/edit)

Code

```
function clearArea() {
    document.getElementById("tarea").value = "This is what's up.";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the main problem is that you forget to wrap your `<script>` tag in the `<head>` tag..

This is working :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clearArea() {
    document.getElementById("tarea").innerHTML = "This is what\'s up.";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="clearArea()">Click me to clear area</button>
<textarea id="tarea"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```